# Form request flask error when trying to submit

Tags: python, flask

i am a beginner programmer in flask and i encounter a problem i rly don't see the problem with my code.

In the login file i have a form and it will send a req to `/check` but i get an err like: `The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

I also have the register file with the action route '/' and this works.

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from models.Data_Base import DataBase

app = Flask(__name__)

db = DataBase()

@app.route('/')
def main_page_render():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login_page_render():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/check')
def check_page_render():
    print('{} {}'.format(request.form['user_name'],  request.form['password']))
    if request.form['user_name'] == 'admin' and request.form['password']:
        return redirect(url_for('admin_page_render'))
    elif db.verify_login(request.form['user_name'], request.form['password']) == True:
        return redirect('/fighter/{}'.format(request.form['user_name']))

@app.route('/admin')
def admin_page_render():
    return 'Admin Page'

@app.route('/fighter/<username>')
def fighter_page_render(username):
    return 'Fighter page'


@app.route('/register')
def register_page_render():
    return render_template('register.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>login_page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login Page</h2>

    <form action="/check">
      <label for="user_name">User name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name"><br>
      <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <p>Click submit in order to get to your account</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The errors comes when you click on "Submit" ?

Comment: instead of /check, try using http://127.0.0.1:5000/check in the html part

Comment: When i pressed submit yes. I tried with 127.0.0.1:5000/check it was same. I have solved it by putting a get and post method to login route. But i still have no idee why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

A Solution can be this, try to do these changes.

app.py
...

```
@app.route('/check', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def check_page_render():
     print('{} {}'.format(request.form['user_name'],  request.form['password']))
     if request.form['user_name'] == 'admin' and request.form['password']:
         return redirect(url_for('admin_page_render'))
     elif db.verify_login(request.form['user_name'], request.form['password']) == True:
         return redirect('/fighter/{}'.format(request.form['user_name']))
```

...

/templates/home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>login_page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h2>Login Page</h2>

  <form action="/check" method="POST">
  <label for="user_name">User name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name"><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

   <p>Click submit in order to get to your account</p>
</body>
</html>
```